# Encode MemoryStream directly to MP3 using NAudio

Tags: c#, naudio

I'm trying to use one of the methods below of the NAudio nuget package:

```cs
MediaFoundationEncoder.EncodeToMp3(new RawSourceWaveStream(_audioStream, _audioWriter.WaveFormat), "Test.mp3", 320000);

using (var reader = new WaveFileReader(_audioStream))
{
    MediaFoundationEncoder.EncodeToMp3(reader, "Test.mp3", 320000);
}
```

This should encode the wav stream directly to mp3. Well it does, but the result only consists of noise.

When I save the same MemoryStream(WaveFileWriter) with

```cs
File.WriteAllBytes("Test.wav", _audioStream.ToArray());
MediaFoundationEncoder.EncodeToMp3(new WaveFileReader("Test.wav"), "Test.mp3", 320000);
```

the created wav file is fine and I can use this wav file to encode it to mp3. But I want to avoid saving the wav file first.

Is there a way to encode the stream directly to mp3 without only getting noise? I have no clue why the one method works and the other isn't. Google didn't help me as well. So maybe you guys have any idea.

Thanks for your effort.

**Further infos:**
.NET Core 3.0 Windows Application
NAudio Nuget Package (Version: 1.9.0)

**Complete class:**

```cs
using NAudio.MediaFoundation;
using NAudio.Wave;
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace Recorder.NAudio
{
    public class Recorder
    {
        private WasapiLoopbackCapture _audioCapture;
        private WaveFileWriter _audioWriter;
        private MemoryStream _audioStream;

        public bool IsRecording { get; private set; }

        public Recorder()
        {
            MediaFoundationApi.Startup();
        }

        public void Init()
        {
            _audioCapture = new WasapiLoopbackCapture();

            _audioStream = new MemoryStream(1024);
            _audioWriter = new WaveFileWriter(_audioStream, new WaveFormat(44100, 24, 2));

            _audioCapture.DataAvailable += DataReceived;
            _audioCapture.RecordingStopped += RecordingStopped;
        }

        private void RecordingStopped(object sender, StoppedEventArgs e)
        {
            _audioCapture.DataAvailable -= DataReceived;
            _audioCapture.RecordingStopped -= RecordingStopped;

            _audioCapture.Dispose();
            _audioCapture = null;
            _audioWriter.Flush();
            _audioStream.Flush();

            _audioStream.Position = 0;

            //This works the mp3 file is fine, but I want to avoid the workaround of first saving a wav file to my hard drive
            File.WriteAllBytes("Test.wav", _audioStream.ToArray());
            MediaFoundationEncoder.EncodeToMp3(new WaveFileReader("Test.wav"), "Test.mp3", 320000);

            //Try 1: This doesn't work the mp3 file consists only of noise
            MediaFoundationEncoder.EncodeToMp3(new RawSourceWaveStream(_audioStream, _audioWriter.WaveFormat), "Test.mp3", 320000);

            //Try 2: This doesn't work the mp3 file consists only of noise
            using (var reader = new WaveFileReader(_audioStream))
            {
                MediaFoundationEncoder.EncodeToMp3(reader, "Test.mp3", 320000);
            }

            _audioWriter.Close();
            _audioWriter.Dispose();
            _audioWriter = null;
            _audioStream.Close();
            _audioStream.Dispose();
            _audioStream = null;

            GC.Collect();
        }

        private void DataReceived(object sender, WaveInEventArgs e)
        {
            _audioWriter.Write(e.Buffer, 0, e.BytesRecorded);
        }

        public void Start()
        {
            Init();

            _audioCapture.StartRecording();
            IsRecording = true;
        }

        public void Stop()
        {
            _audioCapture.StopRecording();
            IsRecording = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. When I change constructor of the WaveFileWriter to this:

```
_audioWriter = new WaveFileWriter(_audioStream, _audioCapture.WaveFormat);
```

And then change the audio settings of my device in the windows sound settings dialog to:
2 Channels, 24 Bit, 44100Hz instead of 2 Channels, 24 Bit, 96000Hz
it works for some reason...