# How can I use NAudio MediaFoundationEncoder to encode an AAC audio file? Plus I'd like clarification on MediaFoundationEncoder encoding

Tags: c#, .net-core, audio, mp3, naudio

Apologies I'm quite new to programming and I need some assistance.

I'm trying to make a desktop app, one of the features of which records audio from the microphone and saves an AAC file.

So far, I have code similar to that provided under this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17982468/naudio-record-sound-from-microphone-then-save), which works:

```
public WaveIn waveSource = null;
public WaveFileWriter waveFile = null;

private void StartBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StartBtn.Enabled = false;
    StopBtn.Enabled = true;

    waveSource = new WaveIn();
    waveSource.WaveFormat = new WaveFormat(44100, 1);

    waveSource.DataAvailable += new EventHandler<WaveInEventArgs>(waveSource_DataAvailable);
    waveSource.RecordingStopped += new EventHandler<StoppedEventArgs>(waveSource_RecordingStopped);

    waveFile = new WaveFileWriter(@"C:\Temp\Test0001.wav", waveSource.WaveFormat);

    waveSource.StartRecording();
}

private void StopBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StopBtn.Enabled = false;

    waveSource.StopRecording();
}

void waveSource_DataAvailable(object sender, WaveInEventArgs e)
{
    if (waveFile != null)
    {
        waveFile.Write(e.Buffer, 0, e.BytesRecorded);
        waveFile.Flush();
    }
}

void waveSource_RecordingStopped(object sender, StoppedEventArgs e)
{
    if (waveSource != null)
    {
        waveSource.Dispose();
        waveSource = null;
    }
```

Of course, this saves a WAV file, not what I want. It seems that to save down an AAC file, I would need to use `MediaFoundationEncoder.EncodeToAac` instead of `waveFile.Write`. The issue I see is that `EncodeToAac` expects an `IWaveProvider` implementation as an input. However, the `WaveInEventArgs` does not seem to to be the same as an `IWaveProvider` implementation although looking at the code for `IWaveProvider` I do see similarities. Can I replace `waveFile.Write` with code that includes `EncodeToAac`?

Elsewhere, I see code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58315672/encode-memorystream-directly-to-mp3-using-naudio) that looks like what I'm tyring to achieve:

```
namespace Recorder.NAudio
{
    public class Recorder
    {
        private WasapiLoopbackCapture _audioCapture;
        private WaveFileWriter _audioWriter;
        private MemoryStream _audioStream;
        // other code
        public void Init()
        {
            _audioCapture = new WasapiLoopbackCapture();

            _audioStream = new MemoryStream(1024);
            _audioWriter = new WaveFileWriter(_audioStream, new WaveFormat(44100, 24, 2));

            _audioCapture.DataAvailable += DataReceived;
            _audioCapture.RecordingStopped += RecordingStopped;
        }
        private void RecordingStopped(object sender, StoppedEventArgs e)
        {
            _audioCapture.DataAvailable -= DataReceived;
            _audioCapture.RecordingStopped -= RecordingStopped;

            _audioCapture.Dispose();
            _audioCapture = null;
            _audioWriter.Flush();
            _audioStream.Flush();
        // other code
        using (var reader = new WaveFileReader(_audioStream))
            {
                MediaFoundationEncoder.EncodeToMp3(reader, "Test.mp3", 320000);
            }
        // other code
        }
    }
}
```

As I understand it, what happens in this code is that a `WaveFileWriter` is writing data to a `MemoryStream`, and then upon completion `EncodeToMp3` encodes this `MemoryStream` into an MP3 file. So this suggests that a entire WAV file has to be stored in memory, and then converted bit-by-bit into an AAC file? Wouldn't it be more efficient to encode to an MP3 as the input is received from the `WasapiLoopbackCapture` instance?

Could someone also please clarify one thing that confuses me as a beginner. It's about something I see in the above example, and in some of Mark's own code [here](https://markheath.net/post/naudio-mediafoundationencoder):

```
using (var reader = new WaveFileReader("input.wav")) 
{ 
    MediaFoundationEncoder.EncodeToMp3(reader, 
            "output.mp3", 48000); 
}
```

The input to EncodeToMp3 is a `WaveFileReader`, which as I understand it inherits from `Stream`. But I thought the first input parameter had to be an `IWaveProvider`. (I'm looking at line 112 of the source file for `MediaFoundationEncoder`.) Could someone please help me understand why this code works?

Thanks to anyone who provides some answers. And thanks especially to Mark for your fantastic library.